# Cordova plugin splashscreen issue while Azure Devops with ant build using android-cordova application

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

Yaml script below where facing issue with cordova-plugin issue

trigger:
'*'

pool:

vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
group: 'MatcoToolskeystoreD'

steps:

script: |

```
 npm i cordova cordova-android@12.0.1
 PATH=$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$PATH; export PATH
 cordova build android
 cordova platform add android
 cordova prepare
```

displayName: 'Install Cordova Dependencies'

script: |

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

displayName: 'Download and setup Cordova plugins'

task: |

env:
JAVA_HOME: $(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)

PATH: $(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)/bin:$(PATH)

inputs:
targetType: 'inline'

```
script: |
    java -version
    ant -f phonegap/build.xml
```

displayName: 'Ant Build'

Find the error logs for cordova-plugin issue below:

[exec] Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
[exec] Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 12.0.1, failed version requirement: >=3.6.0 <11.0.0
[exec] Skipping 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen' for android
[exec] Installing "cordova-plugin-vibration" for android
[exec] The "" tags were detected and are no longer supported. Please migrate to the "preference" tag "AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon".

It is telling to downgrade the version to 10.1.2, but when i am downgrading facing other plugin issue.